# Father brought my plane ticket on his credit card, does he need to come with me to check in?

Tags: tickets, check-in, lufthansa

So I'm leaving from England to Texas in 2 days and was wondering since my Father brought my tickets with his credit card, does he need to be there with the credit card at check in?

He's taking me to the airport so it's possible but will he need to be there on my return flight too? Because obviously that isn't possible since he isn't coming with me

The airline I'm flying with is Lufthansa by the way!

Also just to be sure...check in is before security right? so he would be in and out right? and does this matter if I check in online?

Hope I was clear, thanks for all the help :)

Comment: I have frequently bought Lufthansa tickets for my kids and friends. No problems at check in  as long as the ticket buyer uses his/her Lufthansa account (can't book it anonymously)

Answer (score 3):

Some airlines require the credit card to be supplied at check-in. Some will even prevent you boarding at the gate if you check-in online and have hand luggage only (Cathay Pacific has been known to do this). Some airlines don't obligate you to provide the credit card at check-in if you specify that the person paying is not flying (e.g. British Airways). Some airlines require you to show the credit card on the outbound and the inbound (Royal Jordanian has done that to me). If an airline requires you to show credit card, this is sometimes indicated on the itinerary, and sometimes can be solved by the credit card holder going to an airline office or airport to prove ownership. Some airlines will accept a photocopy of front and back of the credit card.

If your father can accompany you to the airport that would undoutedbly resolve any potential problems. Check-in is before security.